# How to access TotalSummary of ASPxGridView on server side

Tags: c#, aspxgridview

I want to update my ASPx grid view footer for that I need to access TotalSummary on server side can any one help me on same.

I am fetching data as expected but after delete i need to update current value present in Aspx Grid view

**ASPX**

```
 <td>
      <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" cellstyle-horizontalalign="Center" OnHtmlFooterCellPrepared="grid_HtmlFooterCellPrepared"
       KeyFieldName="Ref_ID" OnCustomCallback="grid_CustomCallback" SettingsPager-Mode="ShowAllRecords" Width="100%">
        <Columns>
              <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Ref_ID" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Process No" CellStyle-CssClass="align-text-left"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
              <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Depot" VisibleIndex="0"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
              <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="CostCenter" VisibleIndex="1"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
              <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="GL" VisibleIndex="3"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
              <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Customer" VisibleIndex="4"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
              <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PriceGroup" VisibleIndex="5"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
              
            </Columns>
               <Settings ShowFooter="true" />
               <TotalSummary>
                <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="ProductValueLC" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="ProductValueLC" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="Total: {0:###,##.00}" />
                <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="ProductValueSR" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="ProductValueSR" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="Total: {0:###,##.00}" />
               <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="QTYInPieces" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="QTYInPieces" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="Total: {0}" />
            </TotalSummary>
               <Settings ShowGroupPanel="true" />
               </dx:ASPxGridView>
           </td>
```

I want to update current value which is present in grid

Answer (score 0):

The [DevExpress docs](https://docs.devexpress.com) contains several approaches to access [TotalSummary](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/3757/components/grid-view/concepts/use-data-summaries/total-summary) on server side. One way it´s appropriate for your case is a GridView event called [CustomSummaryCalculate](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomSummaryCalculate).